# What do I label the legend in this regression plot

Tags: regression, labeling

What do I label the predicted values, or fitted model in this chart? (In the legend)
Fitted model? Fit model? Predicted? Regression? What are my options?

The black line and points are the actual results and the gold is the fitted values of the non linear regression.

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes more sense if you label it by the name of the method which produces the result. For example, "Linear Regression".